# Table entry restriction

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Let's say I have two tables:

```
info(id PRIMARY KEY, opendate NOT NULL, closedate)
fileinfo(fileno PRIMARY KEY, id FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES info.id)
```

I would like to allow new entries into fileinfo only if the corresponding value of info.closedate is null.  Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a trigger to the fileinfo table, to run on INSERT, which looks up the closedate on info, and throws an error if it's not null.

EDIT: Added example of a SQLServer trigger which would do the same thing. Edit as MySQL syntax requires.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertFileInfo
   ON  fileinfo
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

    declare @closedate DateTime ;

    select @closedate = closedate from info where id in (select id from new);

    if @closedate is not null
    begin
        raiserror ('CloseDate is not null', 16, 1); 
    end
END
```

Comment: There's tons on info in the internet. Start at e.g. http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Since I'm new to mysql I'm having a tough time writing the code for this trigger.  I looked up the info on the site that you mentioned(I actually had looked that up before) but I'm still not sure how to code this.  In particular I don't know how to refer to a particular closedate value on info table.  I would really appreciate if you could provide me with some sample code so that I could get started!

Comment: I don't have MySQL, but I've amended the answer with a SQL Server one. You'll have to amend it to match MySQL syntax.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! I will try to understand your answer and attempt to convert it if needed to mysql and let you know if it works for me.